# Autodesk Inventor place part at user defined position

Tags: vb.net, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to create a method that will place a file into an assembly, and I want it to be like when you choose place file in Inventor.

The file is been chosen by it's path. And now it needs to be placed. I know a way how to place the file at coordinates, but I want the file to be on the cursor and the user be able to choose where to drop it.

How do you do achieve this? I tried a programming help search but I can only find thing about the event and dialog.

```
FileDialog.InsertMode() As Boolean
```

Normally I just place and ground, but that not good now..

```
Public Function Place_and_Ground_Part(ByVal oDef As AssemblyComponentDefinition,
                                   ByVal path As String) As ComponentOccurrence

    ' Set a reference to the assembly component definintion.
    ' This assumes an assembly document is open.

    ' Set a reference to the transient geometry object.
    Dim oTG As TransientGeometry
    oTG = oInvApp.TransientGeometry

    ' Create a matrix.  A new matrix is initialized with an identity matrix.
    Dim oMatrix As Matrix
    oMatrix = oTG.CreateMatrix

    ' Set the translation portion of the matrix so the part will be positioned
    ' at (3,2,1).
    oMatrix.SetTranslation(oTG.CreateVector(0, 0, 0))

    ' Add the occurrence.
    Dim oOcc As ComponentOccurrence
    oOcc = oDef.Occurrences.Add(path, oMatrix)

    ' Make sure the master part is grounded
    oOcc.Grounded = True
    Return oOcc

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

It certainly isn't obvious how to accomplish what you want, but it is possible, if you know how.  The code below demonstrates using the PostPrivateEvent method where you post the filename of the file you want to insert onto an internal queue within Inventor.  Next, it gets and runs the **Place Component** just the same as if the user were to start the command.  The command first checks to see if a filename is on the private queue and if it is it takes that filename and skips the dialog step.  This results in the user being able to drag and position the occurrence.

```
Public Function Place_and_Ground_Part(ByVal invApp As Application,
                                      ByVal path As String) As ComponentOccurrence

    ' Post the filename to the private event queue.
    invApp.CommandManager.PostPrivateEvent(Inventor.PrivateEventTypeEnum.kFileNameEvent, filename)

    ' Get the control definition for the Place Component command.
    Dim ctrlDef As Inventor.ControlDefinition
    ctrlDef = invApp.CommandManager.ControlDefinitions.Item("AssemblyPlaceComponentCmd")

    ' Execute the command.
    ctrlDef.Execute()

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

You've probably noticed that the function is returning Nothing.  This is a problem using this approach because you execute the command and then turn control over to Inventor.  It is possible to use events to watch and see if a new occurrence is placed and then get it but it complicates the code quite a bit since it's no longer a simple function.

Comment: Thanks brian for that piece of code. it sure helps, but the second bit part of your answer is quite interesting for me. As I would like to do some renaming etc after the place event. Could you show a sample of how I can get the placed object?